# Is PAL (Physics Abstraction Layer) still a viable utility to use?

Tags: physics-engine

In the Wikipedia article on [physics engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_engine) it lists several engines including one that isn't really a physics engine but instead provides a generic physics library and interfaces to several of the popular physics engines.  It's called ["Physics Abstraction Layer"](http://www.adrianboeing.com/pal/index.html) or "PAL".  I'm starting work to integrate a physics engine into a project of mine and am trying to decide which engine to use so this sounds like a great solution because it would allow me to not have to choose and I could write my integration and test it with several engines.  However, when I went to the site for PAL it looks like the code hasn't been touched in the last four years.  Also, when you do a search there are very few results, which would seem to indicate it's not widely used.

Is it dead?  Even if it is, is it still usable and useful?

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Adrian Boeing, the author of PAL, and received a response telling me that PAL is essentially dead. He also told me of a more recent similar project called [PEEL](http://www.codercorner.com/blog/?p=914) but he is unsure of how well it's supported.